# Usar DefaultIfEmpty em uma consulta LINQ com Join

Tags: c#, linq

O objetivo é juntar estas duas lista, sendo que se na lista `pr` tiver um item que não corresponde a lista `un`, sera retornado o valor padrão.
Sei que existem outras maneiras, porém, gostaria de solução utilizando `DefaultIfEmpty`

```
var pr = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var un = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var pu = from p in pr.DefaultIfEmpty(new int())
        join u in un on p equals u
        select p;
    foreach (var i in pu)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

> Resultado: 1,2
>  Esperado: 1,2,0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var pr = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var un = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var pu = from p in pr
            join u in un on p equals u into u1
            from u2 in u1.DefaultIfEmpty(new int())
            select u2;
foreach (var i in pu)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```